use draw.io draw custom shapes but wrong "border points"
I am trying to create some custom irregular shapes using draw.io, but after I draw them, I find that the "connection points" are completely incorrect and not around my shape as I expected. Here are my issues:
1.I tried to adjust these points using "edit connection points," but it didn't work at all. The settings had no effect.
2. Additionally, I want to understand the difference between foreground and background. I didn't understand the explanation in the manual. In the future, I want my shapes to allow the front-end engineer to dynamically switch the fill color. How can I achieve this?
3. When generating shapes, there are parameters h and w in the  tag. I don't understand what these parameters do or if I should set them.
Thank you, and I hope someone can help me answer these questions.
enter image description here
Here is my code:
`    <shape name="stencilName" aspect="variable" strokewidth="inherit">
  <background>
    <fillstroke />
    <strokecolor color="#B3B3B3" />
    <strokewidth width="0.5" />
    <path>
      <move x="0" y="0" />
      <line x="4.5" y="13.4" />
      <line x="82.5" y="13.4" />
      <line x="82.5" y="0" />
      <close />
    </path>
  </background>
  <foreground>
    <fillstroke />
    <path>
      <move x="25" y="10" />
    </path>
    <stroke />
  </foreground>
  <connections>
    <constraint x="0.5" y="0" perimeter="0" name="N" />
    <constraint x="0.5" y="1" perimeter="0" name="S" />
    <constraint x="0" y="0.5" perimeter="0" name="W" />
    <constraint x="1" y="0.5" perimeter="0" name="E" />
    <constraint x="0" y="0" perimeter="0" name="NW" />
    <constraint x="1" y="0" perimeter="0" name="NE" />
    <constraint x="1" y="1" perimeter="0" name="SE" />
    <constraint x="0" y="1" perimeter="0" name="SW" />
  </connections>
</shape>`

1.I tried to adjust these points using "edit connection points," but it didn't work at all. The settings had no effect.
